# The requested member of the collection does not exist, MS Word

Tags: c#, ms-word

I tried to run a sample program from dotnetpearls.com and at first the program didn't work at all.

Apparently I had to run VS Express 2012 as Administrator, before I could start an Application object. After that, the next time it errors out, is when I try to print out the text from the document. Error happens at `string text = doc.Words[i].Text;`

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WordTestProgram
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          Application app = new Application();
          Document doc = app.Documents.Open("C:\\word.doc");

          int count = doc.Words.Count;
          for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++)
          {
               string text = doc.Words[i].Text;
               Console.WriteLine("Word {0} = {1}",i,text);
          }
          app.Quit();
      }
   }
}
```

I know for a fact that the document I am trying to extract data from, does have 3 words and 3 spaces in it. So it's not empty.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer myself

Instead of: `int i = 0; i <= count; i++`

I should do: `int i = 1; i <= count; i++`

Apparently member 0 in the array is null and the program can't handle that.

Comment: Spent an hour on this.  Why does VSTO start collections at 1?  What took so long is when you look in Locals during debugging, the collections clearly start at [0].  Wow.